# Flutter buttons not hiding on first click

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a flutter application and in it, I have join/leave event buttons when the stream comes in it sets the button to either true or false, eg: if a user is in the event it is set to true so the leave button shows up but when I click the leave button I have to click it twice to change before it changes back to the join button when I print the value i can see it change back to true the first click but the UI doesn't change the button back until the second click does anyone know why this is

```
 child: eventStatus
          ? FlatButton(
              child: Text('Leave Event'),
              color: Colors.redAccent,
              onPressed: () async {
                int st = int.parse(eventData.votes);
                int newVotes = --st;
                await DatabaseService.instance.removeVote(
                    AuthService.instance.user.uid,
                    newVotes.toString(),
                    this.widget.event);
                _snackbar.showSnackBarSuccess('OK LEAVE THEN !');
                setState(() {
                  eventStatus = !eventStatus;
                  print(eventStatus);
                });
              })
          : FlatButton(
              child: Text('Join event'),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              onPressed: () async {
                int st = int.parse(eventData.votes);
                int newVotes = ++st;
                await DatabaseService.instance
                    .vote(newVotes.toString(), this.widget.event);
                _snackbar.showSnackBarSuccess('Hey you have friends !');
                setState(() {
                  eventStatus = !eventStatus;
                  print(eventStatus);
                });
              }),
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: set eventStatus to false in inestate()

Answer (score 0):

Use async/await in other function with Future, and call it in onPressed